# Syntax highlight single - quote parameter

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Makefiles can have commands such as:

```
BAR = $(subst ', '\'', $(FOO))
```

Here the first argument to `subst` is a **single** *single quote* resulting in for example:

```
FOO = some ' single ' quotes
BAR = $(subst ', '\'', $(FOO))
@echo "$(BAR)"

some '\'' single '\'' quotes
```

Same goes for **single** *double quotes* as well as things like:

```
BAR = $(subst ", \", $(FOO))
BAR = "$(subst ", \", $(FOO))"
```

The `make.vim` syntax file matches single quoted strings by:

```
syn region  makeSString start=+\(\\\)\@<!'+  skip=+\\.+  end=+'+  contains=makeIdent
```

- `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/make.vim` or the like.

But this does not match single standalone quotes, and the syntax comes out of sync and one get a mess on the lines following.

---

I am not fluent in syn commands. As a quick hack I have added the file `.vim/after/syntax/make.vim` with the contents:

```
syn region makeQarg start=#"\?\$(subst\s\+\(['"]\)\@=#hs=e+1 end=+['"]+
hi def link makeQarg Exception
```

(Use `Error` or the like for *hi def link* if you want to twiddle.)

---

This is not a fix. One issue is that the *keyword* `subst` and the leading `$(` also becomes a part of the match and thus one loose the syntax for that. Not a huge deal, but still.

Any suggestions on a fix?

Comment: You can "fix" the syntax with a comment: `BAR = $(subst ', '\'', $(FOO)) # Fix Vim syntax: '` ... This is really just a workaround, but sometimes it's useful...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Yes. Use that trick from time to time as well, but only if it is rare cases.